# Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to find a character in an alphabetized string... Here is the code

```
def isIn(char, aStr):

        middleChar = len(aStr)//2
        if char == aStr[middleChar]:
            return True
        elif char < aStr[middleChar]:
            LowerHalf = aStr[:middleChar]
            return isIn(char, LowerHalf)
        elif char > aStr[middleChar]:
            UpperHalf = aStr[middleChar:]
            return isIn(char, UpperHalf)
        else:
            return False

print(isIn('a', 'abc'))
```

It returns True. But When I put

```
print(isIn('d', 'abc'))
```

it returns this error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison; instead of False.

I don't understand whats wrong. Please tell me where is the logical mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With d, The program splits the string from abc and picks out `UpperHalf bc`. Then it searches the new string `bc`. It then returns 'c' from 'bc' as expected. Since d > c, the program goes chooses that condition and once again returns the upper half of string 'c', which is c. Hence the recursion. To fix this, you need a separate way of handling length 1 strings.

Comment: Thanks got it... If string length is 1 then that char is definitely in string. Else try break the string into half and now if the length is zero return False.

Answer (score 0):

The last `else` is useless - it will never be executed.

The end of binary search is when the array becomes of one item - if this item isn't the searched one, the searched item isn't in the array.